# Packing data of different sizes into a list of unsigned ints

Tags: python, memory, pack, unpack

I have a set of data that represents a hardware structure that I need to manipulate in python. The real structure is 4 KB in size...I'll just whip up a quick example:

```
Byte(s)  Value  
0-1      0x0102
2-3      0x0304
4-23     "AStrWith20Characters"
24-63    "WoahThisStringHas40CharactersItIsHuge!!!"
64-71    "Only8Chr"
72-74    0x050607
74       0x08
75-127   0x00 (padding)
```

The idea is I pack this structure up into a list of 32 bit Ints, pass the list off to another function, and *that* function then writes the whole shebang out to memory.  The Memory Writing function accepts 64 Bytes at a time, so I'd have to make two calls.

So, for the example above, I'd need to make these calls (I'll use big endian for readability):

```
WrToMemory([0x01020304, 0x41537472, 0x57697468, 0x3230436, 
            0x61726163, 0x74657273, 0x576F6168, 0x5468697, 
            0x53747269, 0x6E674861, 0x73343043, 0x6861726, 
            0x63746572, 0x73497449, 0x73487567, 0x65212121])

WrToMemory([0x4F6E6C79, 0x38436872, 0x05060708, 0x00000000,  
            0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,  
            0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,  
            0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000])
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pack this data in any kind of efficient way.  I have been struggling with using `struct` and `array`, but either I am missing something conceptually or I am simply using the wrong tool for the job.

Ultimately, I know I can write a big hairy function that checks data types, does a bunch of shifting and masking, converts ASCII to hex, and the constructs data packets I need.  But that seems...inelegant.

I figure there's got to be a way to tell python "This is a number that is two bytes long.  Pack it up.  Another two byte number, append it to the last one.  Now this is a string, with 20 bytes.  Append it.  Go on until we have 64 bytes.  Then convert the list of 64 bytes we just made into a lsit of 16 unsigned integers.

It seems like the `pack` and `unpack` functions are what I should be using, but like I said above...I must be missing something.  How does `pack` handle the 3 byte number, for example?  If you use a format string like `HB`, then `pack` expects two arguments:

```
>>> pack('HB', 0x050607)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: pack requires exactly 2 arguments
```

And I can't use `unpack`, because that expects a string, not a number.

Hope I've made my problem clear.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the right tool, but you told pack to encode 2 arguments, but pass in only one.

The string `HB` means: pack two values, one as an unsigned short, the other as an unsigned byte. Pass in two values and it works:

```
>>> pack('HB', 0x0506, 0x07)
'\x06\x05\x07'
```

Just keep experimenting, you'll get the hang of it. Here are the first set of values from your example, in Big Endian notation:

```
>>> pack('>2H20c40c', 0x0102, 0x0304)
'\x01\x02\x03\x04AStrWith20CharactersWoahThisStringHas40CharactersItIsHuge!!!'
```

Note the '>' at the start, this signals the endianess. The strings are converted to sequences and applied as individual variables. Generally, it's easier to just append them though:

```
>>> pack('>2H20c40c', 0x0102, 0x0304) + "AStrWith20Characters" + "WoahThisStringHas40CharactersItIsHuge!!!"
'\x01\x02\x03\x04AStrWith20CharactersWoahThisStringHas40CharactersItIsHuge!!!'
```

Comment: I thought of this, but I think there's some issues here as well.  For example, this makes assumptions about endianness.

Comment: you can define the ['endianness'](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Comment: @Martin, I hadn't intended to submit that response...I hit enter to start a new line and submitted by mistake. :-)

Comment: @Martin: thanks for the reply.  Ultimately, I need to loop through each of the fields of the structure, so each iteration of the loop would need a different format applied.  How would you handle that?  I can only think of detecting the data type, then appending if it's a string and packing if it's a number.  Is that how you'd go about it?

Comment: Is there no structure at all? You couldn't store the different formatters, for example?

Comment: Like this?  
  
    dict = {fmt:H,val:0x0102, fmt:H,val:0x0304, etc}

Answer (score 0):

You can `pack` the whole thing using your struct format, and unpack it using the e.g. 32-bit words format:

```
>>> format="cchi"
>>> p=pack(format,"a","b",1,2)
>>> p
'ab\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
>>> (z1,z2)=unpack("ii",p)
>>> (z1,z2)
(90721, 2)
```

Comment: Note that the OP asks for unsigned ints.